# Criterion for a non-trivial overlap of null spaces of real-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices

I have two large **real-symmetric matrices $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, which obey $A \cdot B = 0 = B \cdot A$**, meaning that they both commute (and thus share eigenvectors) and anticommute.

I am looking for a **simple criterion for checking whether the null spaces of $A$ and $B$ have a non-trivial overlap**. Specifically, I would like to prove that the null spaces of my choice of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal.

For brevity, I speak of "zero eigenvectors" (meaning: elements of the null space) and of "non-zero eigenvectors" (meaning: eigenvectors orthogonal to the null space).

To that end, I recognize that $A\cdot B = 0$ implies that non-zero eigenvectors of $B$ are among the zero eigenvectors of $A$, and likewise $B \cdot A = 0$ means that non-zero eigenvectors of $A$ are among the zero eigenvectors of $B$. However, this still leaves the option that $A$ and $B$ share a non-trivial zero eigenvectors. (By combining the above, one can also show that the sum of the dimensions of the null spaces of $A$ and of $B$ must be *equal or larger than* the dimension $N$ of the matrices. Orthogonality of the null spaces should be equivalent to this bound is saturated -- which is a kind of a test, but I am looking for something that avoids the explicit computation of the eigensystem.)

Thus, I am wondering: Is there a simple algebraic test for proving that the null spaces of such matrices are orthogonal?